# Ruby on Rails - value printed correctly in log but not in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller

I'm trying to fetch a value via my controller and it prints correctly in my logs. However, when I print this in my view it gives an error.

**Controller:**

```
@leads = Lead.all.order('updated_at desc')
    @leads.each do |k|
      if k.lead_propertiesproperty_id = k.lead_properties.map(&:property_id)
        properties = Property.where(:id => property_id)
        category_ids = properties.map(&:property_category_id)
        categories = PropertyCategory.where(:id => category_ids)
        @category_names = categories.map(&:name).exists?

        Rails.logger.debug("categories: #{categories.inspect}")
        Rails.logger.debug("category_names: #{@category_names.inspect}")
      else
        @properties = "No Properties"
        @locations = "No Locations"
      end
    end
    @leads_total = Lead.all.count
```

**View:**

```
  <tbody>
    <% @leads.each do |lead| %>
    <tr class="<%=cycle('odd', 'even') %> location_row" id="lead_row" data-id="<%= lead.id%>">
      <td><%= lead.id %></td>
      <td><%= lead.fullname %></td>
      <td><%= lead.email %></td>
      <td><%= lead.phone %></td>
      <td><%= @category_names.to_sentence %></td>
      <td><%= select_tag :status, options_for_select(Lead.statuses.keys.to_a{|k, v| [k.humanize.capitalize, v]}, lead.status), :class => "lead_status"%></td>
      <td><%= lead.created_at.strftime("%d %b. %Y - %T")%></td>
      <td><%= link_to (fa_icon "pencil-square-o "), edit_lead_path({:id => lead.id, :first_last_name => lead.first_last_name}), :title => 'Edit Lead', :class => "action-button" %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

**The error:**
In the controller log it gives the correct category (eg. desk, virtual, private) value for each lead but in the view it gives the category value from the last lead, for every lead.

Comment: There is no error, it just gives the value of the first lead's property category. "Virtual".. Instead it should give the categories of the row that it's about. I'll add an update in the question.

Comment: It's hard to see where the error is. Try to describe what is desired and what you actually get in the answer. Maybe add comments to the code to show what it's doing.

Comment: In the controller log it gives the correct category (eg. desk, virtual, private) value for each lead but in the view it gives the category value from the last lead, for every lead.

Comment: @JoeWoodward Does this clarify the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly it's because @category_names is being assigned in a loop.

So for example if the first time the loop runs the category is "desk" the @category_names becomes "desk"

However the second time it runs the category becomes "virtual" which overwrites the @category_name variable.

You need to push the category_names into a hash with the ID of the lead

```
@category_names = {}

@lead.each do |lead|
   If lead.category_name.is_what_i_want?
     @category_names[lead.id.to_s] = lead.category_names
    end
  end
```

Very pseudo but that should help you

Then in the view do

@category_names[lead.id.to_s].to_sentence

Comment: Awesome, it almost works. Unfortunately only the to_sentence does'nt work anymore now. I'm guessing because of the .to_s ?

Comment: The error I'm getting is: undefined method `to_sentence' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Never, mind. I fixed it. Had to add  @category_names[k.id.to_s] = [""] to the else part in my controller.